# how to copy the value of a register into another (Logisim)

Tags: cpu, register

how to design the circuit that copy the value of register into the other? I only know the register can be written or loaded, but how is it possible that after loaded the value of 1 register and still keep it?

for example: MOVE Rb, Rc // copies the contents if Rc into Rb

Comment: kind of, but the question is more like how to copy(like the original value stays) the value of 1 register into the other.

Comment: I don't understand. What is your starting point here? Do you already have some type of CPU partially built, but need to add the MOVE instruction? What is your architecture?

Comment: I don't understand the value. Load *is* copy. It's not like loading a 1 into a register takes the 1 away from a different register.

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming for a computer-type system, then what you will have to do is install a 3rd memory unit(this is the RAM in most computers). This memory unit can store the value of the register into one of its vacant spots, copying the contents of the register into said memory. Then, your computer can execute a LOAD instruction to load the byte(or bit group) into your second register.

If your circuit is standalone, you can link the 2 registers with AND gates connected to an ENABLE input. This input will enable copying or not. Then, link the output of said AND gates to the inputs of the second register. This will save the contents of the 1st register to the 2nd register.

Comment: This seems needlessly complex; register-to-register transfers are definitely allowed. It just depends on how you want to design your instruction set.